# Is the theory of linear operators studied as a group theory?

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, infinite-groups

A lot of the [classical Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group) are defined as the subset of the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) known as the [automorphism groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#Automorphism_groups). In sum: they're the set of linear transformations on a vector space that preserve some sort of [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), or similar. The vector spaces of square integrable functions have inner products, and linear transformations that preserve them. For example, the Fourier transform preserves the product:
$$\langle f | g \rangle = \int f^\star(t)\, g(t) \operatorname{d}t.$$

Is there a developed theory of the set of linear transforms that preserve this sort of inner product?

Comment: Norm preserving operators are studied but any group structure that may exist (you need a little bit more than what you have here) isn't really useful. The group would be too large to do much with.

Comment: Interesting. Part of my curiosity is that one thing that separates the solvable "free" quantum field theories is that their Lagrangian takes an inner product like form that allows rotation into momentum space. Given the role symmetries play in [degenerate perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Effects_of_degeneracy), I was curious if there was some analogous role here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group

Comment: You might be interested in any of following various topics: 1. Representation theory (specifically unitary representations), 2. Functional analysis, 3. $C^*$-algebras and spectral theory, 4. Harmonic/Fourier analysis (related to representation theory).

Answer (score 1):

This is the notion of a [unitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator) on a Hilbert space.  They are extremely well studied.